# How to detect dependencies that no longer exist for the latest version

Tags: maven, plugins, properties

I'm using Maven's

> mvn versions:update-property -DnewVersion=[1.0.newversion] -Dproperty=myproperty.version

plugin to upgrade the versions of my dependencies. i.e. Which are keyed off myproperty.version. It works well but I've noticed an issue.

If, in my dependencyManagement, I've keyed a dependency that no longer exists in 1.0.newversion update-property silently ignores the new version.

While it's correct for the version not to be updated. i.e. As this would cause build issues. I'm not happy with  the silent ignore. I'd like to somehow cause a failure. i.e. To inform me something is wrong & needs attention.

Is this possible?

I tried to scrap the console output but it's not unique enough. e.g. I get the same message for invalid versions.

I also tried running with Debug information (e.g. -X) but I hit the same issue.

Comment: Which version of versions-maven-plugin do you use? And second I had expected a message like `...Leaving unchanged as...`?

Comment: I'm using 2.3 of mvn versions. It indeed prints out ...Leaving unchanged as version.... But it does not give a reason. This message is printed if the same version is set or if a version which does not exit is set. I need more fine details.